# How to detect email addresses within arbitrary strings

Tags: ios, email, nsdatadetector

I'm using the following code to detect an email in the string. It works fine except dealing with email having pure number prefix, such as "536264846@gmail.com". Is it possible to overcome this bug of apple? Any help will be appreciated!

```
NSString *string = @"536264846@gmail.com";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];    
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {
        NSString *email = [match.URL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:match.URL.scheme.length + 1];
        NSLog(@"email :%@",email);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"[match URL] :%@",[match URL]);
    }

}
```

**Edit**:
log result is: [match URL] :http://gmail.com

Comment: I just looked at NSDataDetectors - email addresses do not appear to be a supported type - no wonder it does not work.

Comment: @DavidH it does not support

Comment: If its OK with you I'd like to change the title to "How to detect email addresses within arbitrary strings?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did in the past:

- tokenize the input, e.g., separate tokens using spaces (since most other common separators may be valid within an email). However, this may not be necessary if the regular expression is not anchored - but not sure how it would work without the "^" and "$" anchors (which I added to what was shown on the web site).
- keep in mind that addresses may take the form '"string"' as well as just address
- in each token, look for '@', as it's probably the best indicator you have that its an email address
- run the token through the regular expression shown on [this Email Detector comparison site](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) (I found in testing that the [one marked #1](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?view=markup) as of 3/21/2013 worked best)

What I did was put the regular expression in a text file, so I didn't need to escape it:

> ^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))]))$

Defined an ivar:

```
NSRegularExpression *reg
```

Created the regular expression:

```
NSString *fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EMailRegExp" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *error = nil;
reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
assert(reg && !error);
```

Then wrote a method to do the comparison:

```
- (BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString *)string
{
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [reg firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    return match ? YES : NO;
}
```

EDIT: I've turned the above into a [project on github](https://github.com/dhoerl/EmailAddressFinder)

EDIT2: for an alterate, less rigorous but faster, see the comment section of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551458/1633251)

Comment: Well, did you include the text file in your bundle? The assert just says you got an object and no error. I'm actually doing a demo project (for the Mac) myself, as there are some other complexities here, and I want to see if the newer regex works with Apple's regex too. Will update my answer when its done.

Comment: Yes the text file is included. The pattern has value but the reg is nil.

Comment: See the project linked in the EDIT comment. I tested it with a bunch of different addresses and spacing etc. Seems to work well.

Comment: After I change the pattern into either one in your project on github, it works fine now:) How about use the patter such as:     NSString* pattern = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
    return ([predicate evaluateWithObject:string] == YES)? YES:NO;

Comment: You said you want to find URLs in arbitrary text. If your problem is simpler use a simpler solution! What I did was try to be as accurate as possible, not find 80% of all emails. People really do have some of the odd addresses shown in the RFCs.

Comment: I see:) Im curious that how could you create the pattern? It looks so complicated.

Comment: Please email me and let's continue this in a private exchange. You can get my email on my about page. I want to finish what I started and do a good job with mailto.

Comment: "EE turned Mac/iPhone programmer" this what i find on you about me page. Here is my email:echo83426@gmail.com.