# How do I extract a list of email/mailbox strings within text or test if a string is a proper email address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsdatadetector

Given some arbitrary text, I'd like to extract all email addresses and 'mailbox specifiers' (e.g. `"Fred Smith" <fred@me.com>`). I looked at NSDataDetector, but it does not handle email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The way to approach this is to get a really good algorithm that can detect as many valid addresses as possible, and reject improper ones. Probably the best solution would be a parser constructed using lex and yacc, but reasonable solutions exist using regular expressions.

See this [site](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) for both a list of tested regular expressions as well as a more in-depth discussion of the problem and possible solutions.

The regular expressions shown on the above site are formatted for PHP, and have leading and trailing '/' markers, as well as 'flags' indicating case-insensitive etc (see this [site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more info), so these need to be stripped off before using the expression in an Objective-C project. Also, any anchors need stripping too, since we want multiple addresses not just one (i.e., '^' and '$').

NSRegularExpression is the class to use here. What I've found helpful is to store the regular expression in a file in my project, so that you don't need to worry about escaping all the backslashes and quotes. The code then reads the expression into a string, and creates the object as follows:

```
NSString *fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.regex ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
reg = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error]; // some patterns may not need NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
assert(reg && !error);
```

Once you have an initialized expression, you use it to return a list of ranges, each range being an address:

```
NSArray *ret = [reg matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```

However, we know that all email addresses contain one '@', so it's probably worthwhile to verify that the string has at least one before processing it. Also, since the text might have line and/or carriage returns in it, you might want to strip those first. It's probably better to strip them completely as some mail program might have split a line at some interior point of the address.

Once you have a list of the address ranges, then for the most part the job is done - if all you wanted was the address. However, often addresses are presented in "mailbox specifier' format, where a name is prepended to the address, and the address wrapped with '<' and '>'. This format is covered in [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), in section 3.4.

To recover the name from a 'mailbox specifier', check to see if the address is wrapped with '<' and '>', and if so then find the string preceding the '<', ignoring white space (until you find the first character). Most names will be wrapped in double quotes (common practice), but actually can be naked alphanumeric strings using a backslash escape to include white space or other special characters (like '"').

This same technique can be used for real time verification - say to enable a submit button when a text string becomes a valid email address. In this case you evaluate the string on each user change, and enable/disable the submit button.

If all this seems like a lot of work to code, you can grab an open source project on [github](https://github.com/dhoerl/EmailAddressFinder).

EDIT1: for a faster, but less rigorous, method see the comment by CodaFi.

EDIT2: it appears the content of a "mailto: URL can be quite complex, the github project only handles the most simple, and does not un-encode the address. This will be addressed in a future update.

EDIT3: the project was updated to fully handle "mailto:" objects, and returns to, cc, bcc, subject, and body, all URLdecoded.

Comment: NSRegularExpressions can be costly.  Take a look at [EtPanKit's LEPAddress class](https://github.com/CodaFi/etPanKit/blob/master/Source/LEPAddress.m).  It includes a number of methods for converting to and from arrays of address to RFC-standardized strings.

Comment: @CodaFi. interesting project and worth noting. However, I don't see anything in the file you provided that has a real parser in it. Sure, you could look for strings enclosed in '<' and '>', or strings delimited by white space and containing a '@', but you will then get bogus addresses from random text samples. Using the regular expression technique, while slow, will virtually insure what addresses are detected are truely valid. In many cases the speed may not be an issue, but if it is, then alternate faster approaches are for sure warranted.

Comment: It all depends on how they're delimited.  You're right if the array is just garbage with some addresses in it, but for arrays of strings that come, for example, from web-links to email addresses (that activate message composition), it's great.