# Regex Hanging in iPhone For Email Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I am using the following regular expression for email validation:

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.[A-Za-z0-9_]]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-[A-Za-z0-9_]]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})";
NSPredicate *emailRegexPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", firstPartRegex];
return [emailRegexPredicate evaluateWithObject:input]
```

The problem I'm having is that iPhone is hanging when I enter an invalid email that has about 20-25+ characters before the `@` symbol.

For example, the email address `"Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail"` will cause iPhone to hang.
but `"Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com"` will validate normally. `"Abcdefghijklmnopqrst@gmail"` will return invalid immediately.

I notice around 20 characters that it will take longer for regex to return invalid, then incrementing by 1 character will take seemingly exponentially longer.

It seems that it has something to do with this part of the expression:

```
([-.[A-Za-z0-9_]]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*
```

but I can't come up with an alternative that gives the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a project on github](https://github.com/dhoerl/EmailAddressFinder) that has a well tested regex for email - its very very hard to craft one yourself - see [this link on testing various patterns](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). The project has a method `isValidEmail` that you can call iteratively (as say the user taps in info) so you can enable a Submit button etc.

You can read more about the problem and other solutions as well in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526454/1633251).

EDIT: it seems that ambiguity in the regEx can cause cycles that take infinite time to resolve. Since posting this answer I've been working on a "near-perfect" regEx to validate email, all based on the standard. The github project has also been updated, and the validation RegEx is:

> @"^(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\t| )*\r\n)?(?:\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?:
>   )+)?(?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^*`{|}~]+(?:\\.[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+)*)|(?:\"(?:(?:(?:(?:
>   )*(?:(?:[!#-Z^-~]|\[|\])|(?:\\(?:\t|[ -~]))))+(?: )*)|(?:
>   )+)\"))(?:@)(?:(?:(?:A-Za-z0-9?)(?:\.A-Za-z0-9?)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))\.){3}(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))))|(?:(?:(?:
>   )*[!-Z^-~])*(?:
>   )*)|(?:[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\.[-A-Za-z0-9.*~!$&'()*+,;=:]+))\])))(?:(?:(?:(?:
>   )*(?:(?:(?:\t| )*\r\n)?(?:\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?$"

Comment: I'm wondering though what is causing iOS to hang when determining a match does not exist.

Comment: Did you try using the NSRegularExpression class directly? Also, does the A-Z... part need to be inside []?

Comment: OK - you were so nice to give me the answer here - I wrote a demo app and tried using the NSRegularExpression class directly. Your expression compiles without error. However, even using NSRegularExpression, it hung as you observed. Playing with the string, it seems that the '\\' characters are the root cause - take them out and it does not hang. So I uploaded the project to bug reporter:  Bug ID# 13886989

Comment: The \\ is to escape the "." so I'm checking for the "." character in the domain. Your first comment gave me the idea to remove the first "[A-Za-z0-9_]" from "([-.[A-Za-z0-9_]]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*" I realized that was a bit redundant because the next [] grouping handles that case as well. Now it reads "([-.]*[0-9a-zA-Z_])*" and initial testing seems to be successful.

Comment: Don't think you need to escape the period as its enclosed by parenthesis, so its a literal there, no?

Comment: You may be right. All it says on the ICU page is that the metacharacter is not available within sets, which it seems to define as brackets. But this makes sense.

Comment: Last thing - no matter the os should not hang with a bad regex expression. If I ever hear back from Apple will update my answer. Thanks for the thanks.

Comment: I have tested the same expression on http://regexpal.com/ and it causes the site to hang.